# Installing Clockwork Mod using .img

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, 2.1-eclair

I would like to install Clockwork Mod recovery on my Motorola Cliq running Android 2.1. Unfortunately, it seems that the app to install it is no longer available in Market, only in Google Play, but Play doesn't work in 2.1. I was able to download an [image](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager), but have no idea what to do with it. Can somebody walk me through the process? Sorry for the basic question but I'm rather new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The image file goes on the SD card, and then execute the following commands in Terminal Emulator:

```
su
flash_image recovery /sdcard/<filename>
```